# convertir valores double a int

Tags: java

hola mi docente me mando un ejercicio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al momento de codificar eso creo los metodos que me piden pero en el caso de sumar el compilador me salta un error que no se puede convertir un valor double a int

Estos son mis atributos

```
private double valor1;
private double valor2;
```

este es mi metodo sumar aqui me da el error que no se puede convertir un double a int

```
public int sumar(){
    return valor1+valor2;
}
```

entonces nose si el ejercicio que me dio el docente esta mal o yo estoy haciendo algo mal

P.D. No quiero que hagan el ejercicio solo quiero q me aclaren si el ejericio esta bien o esta mal estructurado

Comment: puedes hacer el cast para ambos atributos **return (int)valor1+(int)valor2;**,aunque a mi parecer todos los métodos deberían devolver **double**

Comment: Como comenta dramaturgo, todo debería devolver double. A menos que el objetivo sea truncar decimales, no le veo sentido a que se devuelvan enteros cuando los valores son doubles. En resumen, sí, yo también siento que el ejercicio está mal planteado.

Comment: Yo le pediría una aclaración al profesor(a). Si yo ingreso 3.5 + 2, que espera el profesor(a) que ocurra?